# Batch data processing: Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I am working on C# where I am reading a huge table from 1 database and loading it to my `DataTable`.

Since the table comprises of a huge set of rows (1,800,000+) and I keep getting an out-of-memory error I tried to break it down and copy it 100,000 rows at a time and clear up memory and redo till all the data in the table from the source gets loaded to my `DataTable`.

Can you just look at my code and tell me if I am on the right track? From what it looked to me I was reading the first 100,000 rows again and again and my program is running indefinitely.

Is there a counter I need to be adding to my `DataTable`? So that it adds the next set of rows???
My code snippet is below:

```
    public IoSqlReply GetResultSet(String directoryName, String userId, String password, String sql)
    {
        IoSqlReply ioSqlReply = new IoSqlReply();
        DataTable dtResultSet = new DataTable();
        IoMsSQL ioMsSQL = null;
        int chunkSize = 100000;
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(cs))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {


                        for (int col = 0; col < reader.FieldCount; col++)
                        {
                            String colName = reader.GetName(col);
                            String colDataType = reader.GetFieldType(col).ToString(); ;

                            dtResultSet.Columns.Add(reader.GetName(col), reader.GetFieldType(col));
                        }
                                                 // now copy each row/column to the datatable

                        while (reader.Read())       // loop round all rows in the source table
                        {
                            DataRow row = dtResultSet.NewRow();

                            for (int ixCol = 0; ixCol < reader.FieldCount; ixCol++)     // loop round all columns in each row
                            {
                                row[ixCol] = reader.GetValue(ixCol);
                            }


                            // -------------------------------------------------------------
                            // finished processing the row, add it to the datatable
                            // -------------------------------------------------------------

                            dtResultSet.Rows.Add(row);

                                GC.Collect();       // free up memory

                        }//closing while

                        ioSqlReply.DtResultSet = dtResultSet;       // return the data table
                        ioSqlReply.RowCount = dtResultSet.Rows.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine("DTRESULTSET:ROW COUNT FINAL : " + dtResultSet.Rows.Count);
                        ioSqlReply.Rc = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try limiting the number of rows you get at a time in your SQL statement

Comment: dont use GC.COllect();. that s bad.

Comment: You initialize chunkSize and then never do anything with it.

Comment: Calling GC.Collect(); is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to build a `DataTable` at all. Can't you just write a loop that reads one row and writes it to the destination database directly, without going through the `DataTable`? Also, to echo what others have said, there's no reason to call `GC.Collect`. Doing that for each row just slows down your program. Without it, the garbage collector will do a fine job of managing memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should limit your amount of rows in your Sql for example...

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM SomeTable;
```

if you don't do this, and you have 1.8M in your query, then there is no system able to handle it.

But this will make your app to process only the first 10000 rows... if you need to process all rows, then you should iterate the execution of that sql unitl there are not more rows... for example

```
public IoSqlReply GetResultSet(String directoryName, String userId, String password, String sql)
{
    IoSqlReply ioSqlReply = new IoSqlReply();
    DataTable dtResultSet = new DataTable();
    IoMsSQL ioMsSQL = null;
    bool keepProcessing = true;

    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();

            while (keepProcessing)
            {
               using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
               {
                   using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                   {

                      if (reader.HasRows)
                      {
                        for (int col = 0; col < reader.FieldCount; col++)
                        {
                           String colName = reader.GetName(col);
                           String colDataType = reader.GetFieldType(col).ToString(); ;

                           dtResultSet.Columns.Add(reader.GetName(col),     reader.GetFieldType(col));
                        }
                        // now copy each row/column to the datatable

                        while (reader.Read())       // loop round all rows in the source table
                        {
                            DataRow row = dtResultSet.NewRow();

                            for (int ixCol = 0; ixCol < reader.FieldCount; ixCol++)     // loop round all columns in each row
                            {
                                row[ixCol] = reader.GetValue(ixCol);
                            }


                           // -------------------------------------------------------------
                           // finished processing the row, add it to the datatable
                           // -------------------------------------------------------------

                            dtResultSet.Rows.Add(row);

                            GC.Collect();       // free up memory

                        }//closing while

                        ioSqlReply.DtResultSet = dtResultSet;       // return the data table
                        ioSqlReply.RowCount = dtResultSet.Rows.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine("DTRESULTSET:ROW COUNT FINAL : " + dtResultSet.Rows.Count);
                        ioSqlReply.Rc = 0;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        keepProcessing = false;
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a very rough example... It can be improved but I think it is an easy fix for your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. But will the sql processing not take up a lot of time? As it will iterate through the first 10000 rows then the next 10000 rows and so on.

Comment: Well, processing 1.8 M rows will take some time anyhow, think this... if you have 100 CDs and you need to sort them... how much time would take.. to sort all cds at once, or sort by small groups?

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you running on a 64bit machine?

2) 1,800,000 rows. Assume 1KB per row average. 1.8GB of memory

3) Is there a reason why you have to load everything in memory? Can you stream the data in and work on it one row at a time?

4) Why not just let the DB handle the large tables instead of your client program?

If you're working with large tables of data, you're probably going to have to take a different approach than just loading everything into memory. You're going to need a new design.

edit: It would be helpful to know more of what you're trying to do and how much data you're working with.

Comment: Running on a 32 bit machine. I do need to load all the data to check for data errors and push everything out to a new database. Since am trying to do away with the old database.

Comment: 32bit caps around 2GB of data in memory. The optimal way, if possible, is to load one row, check it for errors, then write out that row to a temp table. Once you're done, have SQL commit the data from that tmp table into your final table. If you can't process a row at a time because of relational data issue that are required to check for errors, you could you group your rows into related data groups and process them as one group at a time. I can't believe that you have to load the entire table in order to check if a given row has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Use a kind of buffering. For example use enumerator with yield return
  and insert several thousand items at once.
  Example for the reading:

  public IEnumerable> ReadFileByLines(string cs, int Buffer = BUFFER)
     {

  ```
      OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(cs);

      OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);

      OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


      List<string[]> bufferList = new List<string[]>(Buffer);

      while (reader.Read())
      {
          bufferList.Add(reader["something"]); // or add a custom class here
          if (bufferList.Count == Buffer)
          {
              yield return bufferList.ToArray();
              bufferList = new List<string[]>(Buffer);
          }
      }

      yield return bufferList.ToArray();
  }
  ```

  ...or create a stored procedure that will server as a paging mechanism, but that will create many roundtrips to the database. Either way the read problem is there, if you're reading 1.8 million rows you have to read them one way or the other.
- Use [BulkInsert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to insert large amounts of data at once to the
  database.
- Ditch the GC.Collect()

Comment: He's reading data from the DB, not inserting. He is "inserting" into a dataset, but it isn't backed by the DB.